# How to develop MFC in VC++ project with VS.NET 2008?

Tags: mfc

people~
I am a .NET developer.
I am very new to Visual C++ project.
But I know 1 thing that I have to use Visual Studio 6 to develop MFC project.
As long as I know, VS 6 only runs on Windows XP which I don't have.
So, I would like to develop the project within VS.NET IDE.
Is there any way to use Visual Studio.NET to develop C++ project?
If possible, does client need to install .NET Framework to run the application?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 (Professional version and up) can develop C++ and MFC applications. The .NET framework is not needed by MFC applications.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How about VS.NET 2010 or 2012? Are they also possible to develop?

Comment: @JoshuaSon: Yes, MFC is available in both versions (not Express editions, you need a VS Professional edition or higher).